# What is the purpose of @Rule in Android Espresso UI Test?

Tags: android, android-espresso

New to Android Unit Testing with Espresso, under @Rule, what is the purpose of creating a member variable? Does the name of the variable matter? I get the inkling that I need to tell the test unit which activity (or service, class) I'm testing, but is the variable and its scope used anywhere I need to care about?

```
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MenuActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MenuActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more practice and reserach with Android UI testing with Espresso, got many of the use cases for the @Rule variables. Of of which is the with testing Idling Resources (View and data that would happen async). Using the ActivityTestRule object (ex. mActivityTestRule) I can reference resources, fire public methods with tag @VisibleForTesting in that class.

ex.

```
// In the activity
    @VisibleForTesting
    @NonNull
    public SimpleIdlingResource getmSimpleIdlingResource()
    {
        if (mSimpleIdlingResource == null)
        {
            mSimpleIdlingResource = new SimpleIdlingResource();
        }
        return mSimpleIdlingResource;
    }

// In the Test class
    // the test is run.
    @Before
    public void registerIdlingResource() {
        mIdlingResource = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getmSimpleIdlingResource();
    }
```